# Find and replace multiple excel files multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I have a lot of xls files in one folder and also in sub folders.
I'd like a vba that find in every file a word for example:
Orange 100 and change it to another word, ex. Pink 150
but I would like also to change
Red 12 in Rose 94
Green 111 in Yellow 212
etc etc etc
So...
Orange 100 Red 12 Green 111
respectively
in 
Pink 150 Rose 94 Yellow 212
any help please?
Thank you so much.
Something like this but in multiple files in folder and subfolders:

```
 Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("Orange 100", "Red 12", "Green 111")
rplcList = Array("Pink 150", "Rose 94", "Yellow 212")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us how you tried to acomplish this task? What errors you get when you try? We are not a code-makers, we help you with the questions about errors you have when you try. Please read this: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. What you miss is the openining of multiple workbooks in folders and subfolders. So this is the code I add for you.

We are using recursion to iterate your file system using the FileSystemObject so add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Run time to your project/workbook. in Excel code window menus >>tools>>references.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Multi_FindReplace(wb As Workbook)
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fndList As Variant
    Dim rplcList As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    fndList = Array("Orange 100", "Red 12", "Green 111")
    rplcList = Array("Pink 150", "Rose 94", "Yellow 212")

    'Loop through each item in Array lists
      For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
          For Each sht In wb.Worksheets 'changed Active workbook to the workbbok passed as argument
            sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
              LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
              SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
          Next sht

      Next x
End Sub
Public Sub FindReplace()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    folderPath = "C:\workbooks\" 'start folder modify to fit your case
    recurseFolderReplacing FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
End Sub
Private Function recurseFolderReplacing(myfolder As Folder)
    Dim myfile As File, mySubFolder As Folder
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each myfile In myfolder.Files
        'filter to ensure we only touch excel files
        If Right(myfile.Name, 5) = ".xslx" Or Right(myfile.Name, 4) = ".xsl" Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myfile.Path, False, True)
            Multi_FindReplace wb
            wb.Close True
            Debug.Print "Processed " & myfile.Path
        End If
    Next

    'the recursive calls to subfolders
    For Each mySubFolder In myfolder.SubFolders
        recurseFolderReplacing mySubFolder
    Next
End Function
```

I have not tested the code so tell me how it goes.

Bikxs

Comment: @acquisti  Replace  "wb.Close Save" with " wb.Close true". This line saves the file after modifications